# How do i invoke Javascript function (GMap API) from JavaFX Button

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps-api-3, javafx

I'm Making a JavaFX Application, Which could interact with the Google Maps( JavaScript APIs),  I have a Separate HTML file (Includes JavaScript) and the Java File, Here is the HTML file, Containing the Method fun, Which is want to invoke From the JavaFX Button :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { height: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 40.003584, lng: -98.270542},
zoom: 3,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.STANDARD,
disableDefaultUI: true
});






var triangleCoords = [
  {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
  {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
  {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
];

// Construct the polygon.
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: triangleCoords,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 0,
strokeWeight: 3,
fillColor: '#FF0000',
fillOpacity: 0.35
});
bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

var fourCoords = [
{lat: 45.192438, lng: -122.494893},
{lat: 45.152075, lng: -117.971829},

{lat: 43.013805, lng: -118.372606},
{lat: 43.222766, lng: -122.666655}
];

var four = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: fourCoords,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 0,
strokeWeight: 3,
fillColor: '#FF0000',
fillOpacity: 0.35
});


four.setMap(map);

}
function fun(){
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
drawingControl: true,
drawingControlOptions: {
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
  drawingModes: [
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
  ]
},
markerOptions: {icon: 'images/beachflag.png'},
circleOptions: {
  fillColor: '#ffff00',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 5,
  clickable: false,
  editable: true,
  zIndex: 1
}
});
drawingManager.setMap(map);
}


</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCvmQrbmioMiGTZQRwp6Bp55s_1Ju7GIl4&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And In my java File, I have the following code to invoke the Function fun() :

```
    final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("map.html");
    webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());

    add_button.setOnAction(e -> webEngine.executeScript("document.fun()"));
```

and when I click on the Button (add_button), It throws this Exception as the Statement "webEngine.executeScript("document.fun()"));", is not being executed with respect to the map.html, instead its executing it separately, How Can i make it execute the statement in context with he map.html , I want the users to be able to draw On the screen after they click the add_button  :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'document.fun()')
at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:128)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1439)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:982)
at Medow$mapScript.lambda$new$0(Medow.java:635)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can i solve this, or Should i use some other approach, as i want heavy interaction between JavaScript and the Java Code.

Comment: found the Solution, It may help someone : declaring a function in HTML/js file as document.<func_name> = function(Param List){ //func definition }, allows executing a JavaScript function using the "webEngine.execute("document.<func_name>(Param List);");", whereas the same cannot be done, if the function is defined, as function <func_name>(){//definition}.

Comment: in my html file, i have this function:
document.addPoint = function(latitude, longitude, wind, temp, light){ //func definition}
and in my java code, when I run :
engine.executeScript("document.addPoint({-27.487000},{152.984000},{10},{10},{10});");
I got this error : 
"Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'. Expected a property name."
any clues?